# Best way for checking new files which need to be processed

Tags: php, directory-structure

This is more a general question than really a language-specific one. I have to implement a program, which automatically processes csv files (read the file, write to database, move file). This isn't the problem at all.

The problem is - I've a **directory structure** like the following one and have to check regularly (will be like 5 minutes or so) if there are any new files in it which need to be processed...

```
-+ basedir
--+ AT (ISO country abbreviation ...)
--+ DE
---+ ID1234 (directory for user)
---+ ID2345
---+ ID4523
---+ ...
```

Do you have any idea how to go through each directories in a very performant manner? I don't think that it's that good to perform a loop over all directories and scan them.

Files get uploaded via FTP and I've full control over the server.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Watching the log on your FTP server is a good idea, especially if you have a lot of subdirectories to scan.  A *`tail`* avoid the overhead of a polling solution, and will tell you precisely where to look for files.  But that's something that would be achieved more easily using shell than PHP, I think.

I have vsftpd on one server, which generates logs that include lines like this:

```
Fri Feb 24 05:37:43 2012 [pid 86561] [bob] OK UPLOAD: Client "10.2.3.4", "/path/to/file.txt", 6036 bytes, 32.77Kbyte/sec
```

To trigger actions based on this, I could use a shell script like the following:

```
#!/bin/sh

tail -F /var/log/vsftpd.log | while read junk junk junk junk junk junk junk user status command junk sourceip file junk; do
  if [ "$command" = "UPLOAD:" -a "$status" = "OK" ]; then
    if echo "$file" | grep -q '/path/to/.*\.txt'; then
      # do some triggered action, like:
      sql="INSERT INTO log VALUES ('$user', '$sourceip', '$file')"
      if mysql -uusername -ppasswd -Ddbname -e"$sql"; then
        filename="`echo \"$file\" | sed -r 's/\"(.*)\",$/\\1/'`"
        mv "$filename" /path/to/donefiles/
      fi
    fi
  fi
done
```

This could be started using your OS's normal startup facilities, or launched by cron using a `@reboot` special.

Add error handling to taste.

Comment: sounds quite good so far. have to check that out. thank you in the meanwhile :-)!

Answer (score 0):

You can setup logging for ftp and parse the log for new events.

Or try something like inotify, fschange, audit, ...